# Accept YYYY-MM-DD but not a completely empty input

Tags: html, regex

I am attemtping to do validation via HTML5 pattern and regex. I want to only accept dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I tried to find one, and I found this: `([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))`. However, when I [test it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXMxEV), it accepts an empty input.

Could someone help me fix this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Add `required`.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/hN08Pi/1) might help you to match your inputs:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: That pattern is a lot less restrictive than the OP's pattern.

Comment: @Emma It turns out it didn't work because of the space you added. But as mentioned, this isn't as restrictive. Thanks anyway.